# "IOError: [Errno ftp error] 200 Type set to I" when installing lxml from source

Tags: python, lxml, urllib, setup.py, ftplib

This is my error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install scrapy --upgrade

Requirement already up-to-date: scrapy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: Twisted>=10.0.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: w3lib>=1.15.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: queuelib in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)

Collecting lxml (from scrapy)

  Using cached lxml-3.6.4.tar.gz

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Building lxml version 3.6.4.
    Retrieving "ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/libxslt-1.1.26.win32.zip" to "libs\libxslt-1.1.26.win32.zip"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\thezm\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y3m3fl\lxml\setup.py", line 233, in <module>
        **setup_extra_options()
      File "c:\users\thezm\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y3m3fl\lxml\setup.py", line 144, in setup_extra_options
        STATIC_CFLAGS, STATIC_BINARIES)
      File "setupinfo.py", line 55, in ext_modules
        OPTION_DOWNLOAD_DIR, static_include_dirs, static_library_dirs)
      File "buildlibxml.py", line 95, in get_prebuilt_libxml2xslt
        libs = download_and_extract_zlatkovic_binaries(download_dir)
      File "buildlibxml.py", line 55, in download_and_extract_zlatkovic_binaries
        urlretrieve(srcfile, destfile)
      File "c:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
        return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
      File "c:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
        fp = self.open(url, data)
      File "c:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 213, in open
        return getattr(self, name)(url)
      File "c:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 558, in open_ftp
        (fp, retrlen) = self.ftpcache[key].retrfile(file, type)
      File "c:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 906, in retrfile
        conn, retrlen = self.ftp.ntransfercmd(cmd)
      File "c:\python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 334, in ntransfercmd
        host, port = self.makepasv()
      File "c:\python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 312, in makepasv
        host, port = parse227(self.sendcmd('PASV'))
      File "c:\python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 830, in parse227
        raise error_reply, resp
    IOError: [Errno ftp error] 200 Type set to I

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\thezm\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y3m3fl\lxml\
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: `[Errno ftp error] 200 Type set to I` it seems there is problem with FTP server. Maybe try tomorrow. Or try to download `ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/libxslt-1.1.26.win32.zip` and install manually.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to [a bug in `ftplib` and/or `urllib`](http://bugs.python.org/issue25458): FTP response 226 is ignored, causing the client to incorrectly match further incoming responses with outgoing commands.

I did some digging and came to the conclusion that `urllib` can't be fully fixed with `ftplib` as it's now. You can use the following patch to `urllib.py` to fix this specific problem though (the diff is for Python `2.7.12`):

```
--- a/urllib.py Sat Jun 25 22:46:20 2016
+++ b/urllib.py Sat Dec 10 00:20:48 2016
@@ -927,7 +927,7 @@
         self.busy = 1
         ftpobj = addclosehook(conn.makefile('rb'), self.file_close)
         self.refcount += 1
-        conn.close()
+        #conn.close()
         # Pass back both a suitably decorated object and a retrieval length
         return (ftpobj, retrlen)

@@ -940,7 +940,14 @@
             self.real_close()

     def file_close(self):
+        import ftplib
         self.endtransfer()
+        #Process the 226 transfer complete response
+        try:
+            self.ftp.voidresp()
+        except ftplib.error_temp as msg:
+            # transfer is aborted by urllib when some other exception has happened
+            if msg.args[0][:3] != '426': raise
         self.refcount -= 1
         if self.refcount <= 0 and not self.keepalive:
             self.real_close()
@@ -990,15 +997,13 @@
         self.hookargs = hookargs

     def close(self):
-        try:
-            closehook = self.closehook
-            hookargs = self.hookargs
-            if closehook:
-                self.closehook = None
-                self.hookargs = None
-                closehook(*hookargs)
-        finally:
-            addbase.close(self)
+        addbase.close(self)
+        closehook = self.closehook
+        hookargs = self.hookargs
+        if closehook:
+            self.closehook = None
+            self.hookargs = None
+            closehook(*hookargs)


 class addinfo(addbase):
```

Comment: sorry but it didn't work for me, i use urllib2 instead.

Comment: @Statham that means you have a different problem than the one outlined in this question. Ask it as another one.

Comment: thanks @ivan_pozdeev, it worked for me :) I only not included the snippet for `def close(self):`

Comment: @IgordeLorenzi IIRC the `close` part is for acting correctly when the transfer connection has been killed by `urllib` (e.g. can't open the local file).